# What's the first person singular future of победить

Tags: грамматика, глаголы, tense, будущее-время, defective-verbs

What is the first person singular of победить in future tense? The other person-numbers have obvious forms such as:

> ты победишь, мы победим, они победят, вы победите, он победит, я ???

The obvious "победю" hits the ear wrong. Of course one could use workarounds such as

> Победа будет за мной.
>
> Я одержу победу.

But I am interested in the grammatical aspect here.

- Is there a correct form for first person singular future of this verb?

If not

- Was there ever one?
- Are there other verbs that lack one or more person-number forms but have others?

Comment: Yes, the best way to say that is to use this workaround: "Я одержу победу".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Д. Э. Розенталь. Справочник по правописанию и стилистике](http://rosental.virtbox.ru/styli_xl.html#sect171):

> § 171.
> Образование некоторых личных форм
>
> 1. Глаголы "победить, убедить, очутиться, ощутить, чудить" и некоторые другие, принадлежащие к так называемым недостаточным
>    глаголам (т. е. глаголам, ограниченным в образовании или употреблении
>    личных форм), не образуют формы 1-го лица единственного числа
>    настоящего-будущего времени. Если необходимо употребить эти глаголы в
>    указанной форме, используется описательная конструкция, например:
>    сумею победить, хочу (стремлюсь) убедить, могу очутиться, попытаюсь
>    ощутить, не буду чудить.
>
> Не употребляются из-за фонетического совпадения с формами от других глаголов такие формы, как «бужу» (от бузить, ср. бужу от
> будить), «держу» (от дерзить, ср. держу от держать), «тужу» (от
> тузить, ср. тужу от тужить) и некоторые другие.
>
> Глаголы умертвить, роптать образуют в l-м лице единственного числа формы умерщвлю, ропщу.
> в приведенном примере буд.время возможно для глагола умертвить.

Comment: Used to have a hard copy of this book. Lost it :( Good to know there's an online version. +1

Comment: Please note that in fact "бужу" and "держу" is very commonly used.

Comment: @Putnik: Of course they are. But they are used only as forms of будить and держать, respectively, and never as forms of бузить or дерзить.

Comment: @Armen I find it amusing how well `будить + держать` goes together with `бузить + дерзить`. I cannot get rid of that mental image.

Answer (score 22):

First person singular of `победить` in future tense *was* `побежду`. Below is the picture from the "Extensive Russian Grammar" book ("Пространная русская грамматика", 1830). But now this form is considered obsolete.

[image: Extensive Russian Grammar]

Comment: А может быть, автор книги просто не мог допустить пропусков в своих таблицах и подбросил монетку?

Comment: @Nakilon He wasn't alone. See [this](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/2996/12766) answer