# Why can't we say "I'll win" in Russian using only one word for "win"?

Tags: одним-словом

Why can't we say "I'll win" in Russian using only one word for "win"? Of course, we can use "одержу победу" (any other synonyms?). Maybe in the past it was possible and then for some reason the word became archaic? 
Any info is appreciated!

Comment: As a result of discussion with @Dmitry Alexandrov, it seems "побежду" is acceptable (Илиада, пер. Н.И. Гнедича): 
http://glossword.info/index.php/term/73-raznlichnye-terminy-i-opredelenija,3038-pesn-tret-ya-klyatvy-smotr-so-steny-edinoborstvo-aleksandra-i-menelaya-.xhtml  (in the end).

Comment: Этот глагол относится к недостаточным. Такие глаголы не имеют всех возможных шести личных форм.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the first person singular future of победить](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/99/whats-the-first-person-singular-future-of-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: Definitely a duplicate. The 19-th century form was "я побежду"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Чего это «we can’t»? Я вот могу: «*Я побежу́*». :-) Это абсолютно корректная грамматически форма (ср. с *доложу́*, *остужу́*, *подтвержу́* и пр.), которая однако по некоторым причинам широко не употребляется.

При этом стоит заметить, что это не единственная глагольная форма на *-жу* , которой русскоговорящие избегают: из того же единственного числа первого лица будущего времени можно вспомнить, например, *убежу́* (от *убеди́ть*), *отчужу́* (от *отчуди́ть*), из настоящего времени: *держу́* и *бужу́* от *дерзи́ть* и *бузи́ть*.

Наиболее правдоподобное об’яснение этому в том, что, как вы уже могли заметить, эти слова в точности совпадают с теми же грамматическими формами других, причем более распространенных, слов, а именно: *побежу́* от *побежа́ть*, *убежу́* от *убежа́ть* (формы не литературные, но существующие или по меньшей мере существовавшие), *отчужу́* от *отчужда́ть*, *держу́* от *держа́ть* и *бужу́* от *буди́ть*.

Из неправдоподобных гипотез мне на просторах Сети встречалось утверждение, что «я побежу» было табуировано, чтоб не сглазить. Неправдоподобна она во-первых потому, что никак не об’ясняет трудностей c тем же *убедить* и другими словами. А во-вторых потому, что в родственных языках, где смешения *побежу* / *побегу* не было, никакого «табу» не возникло: по-белорусски будет *я перамагу́*, по-украински *я перемо́жу*.

Форма *победю́* грамматически некорректна и, как справедливо заметил @alex, употребляются только в юмористическом контексте.

> А стрелок: — Да это что за награда?
>   Мне бы выкатить портвейна бадью!
>   Мол, принцессу мне и даром не надо —
>   Чу́ду-ю́ду я и так победю.
>   [В. Высоцкий. Про дикого вепря]

*Побежду́* же, насколько я могу понять, — это корректная церковнославянская форма.

> 24 И ссѣку ѿ лица єгѡ враги єгѡ, и нєнавидѧщыѧ єго побѣжду:
>   [Псалом 88, Елизаветинская библия]

Откуда она проникла в русский, где эпизодически использовалась в текстах высокаго штиля.

> Коль любишь ты меня, пусть твой отец стремится
>   Взнесенный на меня низринуть свой удар;
>   Ко дщери я его храня во сердце жар,
>   Несправедливости его опровергая,
>   Умру иль побежду, Рамиду обожая.
>   [Я. Б. Княжнин. Вадим Новгородский, 1789]
>
> Я теку на брань и побежду; хощу, да по прибытии моем в Киев, когда сердца народные упоеваться будут радостию, — хощу, да первый, кто поздравит меня с победой, — будет прелестная София.
>   [В. Т. Нарежный. Славенские вечера, 1809]
>
> Так, сегодня Атрид победил с ясноокой Афиной;
>   После и я побежду: покровители боги и с нами.
>   [Илиада в переводе Н. И. Гнедича, 1809–1829]

А возможно и более широко, по крайней мере именно ее дают как единственно возможную Н. И. Греч в своей «Пространной русской грамматике» (1827) и Я. К. Грот в «Русском правописании» (1902).

Из однословных синонимов можно отметить *вы́играю [в чем-либо]* и *одоле́ю [кого-либо]*, последнее относится к несколько возвышенному стилю.

P. S. После всего вышесказанного мне, кстати, перестают казаться иронией  строки из «Фортуны» М. И. Цветаевой (1919):

> В который раз дивлюсь
>   Убожеству мужского лексикона!
>   Какое нищенство! Люблю, убью —
>   Убью — люблю… Нет, наш словарь — богаче!
>   Взойду, взгляну и побежду… Взгляну —
>   И не возьму...

Нет, действительно: здесь «побежду» употреблено серьезно?

P. P. S. Гуглопереводчик понимает *Я побежу* таки как *I will run*, *Я победю* — как прошедшее *I won*, *Я побежду* — корректно определяя стилистическую разницу, но все равно как прошедшее *I defeated*.

Comment: +1 за примеры, но вопрос остается: почему эта форма не употребляется? 
Кстати, почему побежать и убежать не литературные формы? И вроде бы нет никакого совпадения, препятствующего использованию "побежу": побежать - побегу, победить - побежу.

Comment: "Одолею" не подходит, пожалуй. "Одолею" обычно употребляется с указанием, кого именно одолею.

Comment: @TT_ Я не вполне ясно выразился. Сейчас попробую поправить. От _убежать_ существовала именно форма ед. ч. 1 л. буд. вр. _убежу_. А от _побежать_ — _побежу_.

Comment: Когда существовала? Известно ли, почему не употребляется сейчас?

Comment: Мне почему-то "побежду" кажется более естественным, чем "побежу".

Comment: @TT_ Да по мне они и сейчас существуют — регулярно натыкаюсь. Кстати, в этом можно косвенно убедиться поискав ни с чем не смешивающиеся словоформы _забежу_ или _выбежу_.

Comment: @TT_ Вероятно потому кажется, что вы ее неоднократно встречали. Как я уже неявно упомянул, это вроде бы нормальная церковнославянская форма (_И ссеку от лица его враги его, и ненавидящыя его побежду_ — псалом 88), а поэтому в текстах высокого стиля вполне себе употреблялась, ну напр. _Так, сегодня Атрид победил с ясноокой Афиной; / После и я побежду: покровители боги и с нами._ (Илиада в пер. Гнедича)

Comment: "Побежу", действительно, легко в разговоре можно понять как "побегу", т.е. в орпеделенном смысле противоположный смысл от подеды.

Comment: For me, "I'll win" is closer to "я выиграю" (in the lottery, in the card game, etc.) than to "я побеж(д)у", which I would translate back as "I'll prevail" (in the battle or in the argument). However, if we allow synonyms, the options become endless in both languages.

Comment: @fedja Maybe. But it’s quite obvious that the question was about one of the forms of *победить*. ;-)

Comment: Я заминусил, потому что де-факто это форма не просто не употребляется а считается некорректной, поэтому говорить, что это форма "широко не употребляется" - это вводить в заблуждение.

Comment: @shabunc Кем считается (только без детских книжек, пожалуйста)? Грамматика — штука точная, и корректная форма, образование которой для носителей языка затруднено по внеграмматическим причинам, от этого грамматически некорректной не становится.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov статистикой как минимум

Comment: "Я побежду корректно как I defeated." - корректно???

Comment: @Anixx, спасибо. :-) Интересно даже, ибо уже не помню, что́ я тогда хотел написать — наверное, что стилистику Гугль определяет корректно.

Answer (score 2):

You can say:

```
Я выиграю

Я выиграю в этой битве
Я выиграю в этой борьбе
Я выиграю в этой игре
```

You can't say "I'll win" fom the world победить. But unexiting word "победю" some times used as a joke because it's sound funny for Russian ear.

This is an example from the Vladimir Vysotsky song "Про дикого вепря":

```
А стрелок: – Да это что за награда?
Мне бы выкатить портвейна бадью!
Мол, принцессу мне и даром не надо –
Чуду-юду я и так победю.
```

http://nvris.ucoz.ru/text/Visotski-3.htm

Comment: Yes, I was going to mention the Vysotsky's song as well :) 
Still, the question is _why_. Just because?

Comment: As I already said, it's sound funny and non-Russian.

Answer (score 0):

Мы не говорим так! Можно так сказать только ради шутки и только лишь! Надо просто найти подходящий эквивалент этому выражению i'll win.

Я выиграю битву.
Я смогу победить в этой битве.
Я сделаю тебя сегодня! (в матче, в игре).

Comment: Вопрос "не как сказать", а "почему не говорят". Вот в 1830 году форма будущего времени [была в справочниках](http://russian.stackexchange.com/a/116/551), а сегодня не употребляется.